# I want to use boto3 in async function, python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, python-asyncio

I am developing web-scraper in playwright and want to upload images to aws-s3 asynchronouslly.

but boto3 is not an async function.. how to fix it?

```
class Boto3:
   def __init__(self, key, id):
       self.S3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=aws_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret)

   def upload_stream(self, stream, bucket_name, key):
       self.S3.put_object(Body=stream, Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key)

...
...

class Scraper:
   def __init__(self, key, id):
      self.S3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=id, aws_secret_access_key=key)

   asnyc _save_image(res):
      buffer = await res.body()
      # S3.put_object is not an async function.
      self.S3.put_object(
            Body=buffer, 
            Bucket=bucket_name, 
            Key=bucket_key,
      )

   async def scrape():
      playwright = await async_playwright().start()
      browser = await playwright.chromium.launch( headless = True, devtools = False )
      page = browser.new_page()

      page.on('response', _save_image)
      await page.goto('https://www.example.com')

scraper = Scraper(key, id)
asyncio.run(scraper.scrape())
```

self.S3.put_object : this func is not an asnyc so want to change it with in async-version.
How to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How to fix it?

You can't, as `boto3` is not async. At best you can try a third party, non-AWS library, such as [aioboto3](https://pypi.org/project/aioboto3/) in place of `boto3`.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) and [partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

By using `loop.run_in_executor`, the synchronous function call (`put_object`) can be executed (in a separate thread) without blocking the event loop.

`partial` is just used to set function arguments in advance for more readability and clean code

```py
from functools import partial

class Scraper:
   def __init__(self, key, id):
      self.S3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=id, aws_secret_access_key=key)

   asnyc _save_image(res):
      buffer = await res.body()
      loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

      put_object_partial = partial(
         self.S3.put_object,
         Body=buffer, 
         Bucket=bucket_name, 
         Key=bucket_key
      )

      await loop.run_in_executor(None, put_object_partial)
      
   ...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.7+

You can use [asgiref](https://pypi.org/project/asgiref/) for such a things. It can convert sync function to async and backwards.

```
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

@sync_to_async
def _save_image(res):
      buffer = await res.body()
      # S3.put_object is not an async function.
      self.S3.put_object(
            Body=buffer, 
            Bucket=bucket_name, 
            Key=bucket_key,
      )

# And then you can call it as async
async def main():
    await _save_image(res)
```